# Convert to java 8 lambda

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, java-8

What is the best way convert following traditional java validation into java 8 functional programming way?

```
if (obj != null) {
    if(obj.isValid) {
     someService.update(obj);
  }
}
```

obj is an `Optional` instance.
Eg:

```
Optional<Car> obj = Optional.ofNullable(dao.getCar())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
obj.filter(e -> e.isValid).ifPresent(someService::update)
```